# Optimizing the ANTLR4 C++ runtime

Tags: c++, antlr4

After profiling the antlr4 C++ runtime,
I replaced the "is < ClassName > " calls that uses dynamic casting to check a class type in the most prominent places by an old school isType technique that uses a bit masking for each class, very C like technique, I gained about 20% over my regression in runtime.

The next runtime offender in line is:

ParserATNSimulator.cpp

```
auto onExit = finally([this, input, index, m] {
  mergeCache.clear(); // wack cache after each prediction
```

Invoking:

```
void PredictionContextMergeCache::clear() { _data.clear(); }
```

which invokes an unordered_map clear which in turn invoke an expensive memset to 0.
I wonder if there is no other faster implementation possible here.

Thanks
Alain

Comment: The code looks incomplete

Comment: The `is<>` template function has been modeled after the same function in Java, to stay close (code-wise) to the Java runtime. Often the tested object has a type field, which could be used instead of `is<>`. The main problem wrt speed in the runtime is probably the often used shared_ptr to manage certain objects. Also that prediction merge context uses them and clearing the map involves also (potentially) freeing the referenced objects. I don't see how you can optimize this, except by completely reworking memory handling in the runtime.

Comment: @MikeLischke You seem to be asking how to make `mergeCache.clear()` faster. How is that related to the `is<ClassName>` template?

Comment: @palotasb Read the question again. The second part is about clearing the merge cache.

Comment: @MikeLischke You seem to be asking about clearing the merge cache. How is that related to the `is<ClassName>` template?

Comment: Hi Mike, sorry for the confusion I created. I took care of the is ClassType, that is not anymore on the profiling radar.

Comment: Hi Mike, sorry for the confusion I created. I indeed took care of the is ClassType performance issue, by doing classtype data member bitfield checks which works super fast, that is not anymore on the profiling radar. The question is about the new top profile contributor: the clearing of the merge cache. Since this is called very often (N) and each time clears the complete array using a memset (M), it is of N*M order. Is there another container that could possibly be used to clear say just the 1rst element? Reducing the complexity of this operation?

Comment: I found a way around this, I simply clear the cache only 1 out of 20 times, the memory impact is negligible, the runtime is another 20% faster and the results is identical.